# Find $x$ in equation having Euler's Number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have to find $x$ in this equation. I have already tried cross multiplying but I am not sure what to do after. 
$$
\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}} = \frac{3}{4}
$$

Comment: Do you know about the hyperbolic functions?

Comment: @pie314271 not yet. we are still in logarithmic functions in class.

Comment: Format your questions properly!

Comment: @tired sorry i will try fixing it. the formatting wont show up earlier :(

Comment: Hint set $z=e^x$ and solve the resulting quadratic equation

Comment: Yes, in that case you would just use tired's method.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=e^x$. Then

$$\frac{z-z^{-1}}{z+z^{-1}}=\frac34,$$

which leads to the quadratic equation

$$4(z^2-1)=3(z^2+1),$$

or

$$z^2=7.$$

Hence $x=\dfrac{\log7}2$, which is the only solution.

Comment: (Independently of @tired).

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-componendo-and-dividendo-rule

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$\sinh x =\frac {e^x -e^{-x}}{2} $$ and that  $$\cosh x =\frac {e^x + e^{-x}}{2} $$ Can you now proceed where $\sinh x $ and $\cosh x $ are [hyperbolic trigonometric functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function)?

---

We can otherwise put $k =e^x $ and then get our equation as $$\frac {k-\frac {1}{k}}{k+\frac {1}{k}} =\frac {3}{4} $$ $$4 (k^2-1) =3 (k^2+1) $$ $$\Rightarrow k = \sqrt {7} \text { as an acceptable solution} $$ Hope it helps.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to just state that the equation is $\tanh(x)=3/4$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution **without** the use of **hyperbolic trigonometric functions**.

We have:

$$\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{3}{4}$$

Let's multiply both the numerator and denominator of the left hand side by $e^x$:
$$\frac{(e^x-e^{-x})\cdot e^x}{(e^x+e^{-x})\cdot e^x}=\frac{3}{4}$$
$$\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}=\frac{3}{4}$$

Now, you can substitute $u=e^{2x}$, and obtain a **linear equation** after doing cross-multiplication:
$$\frac{u-1}{u+1}=\frac{3}{4}$$
You can now easily solve for $u$, and substitute back $u=e^{2x}$. Then, solve for $x$.

If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to ask.